# Issue with Array/Curve modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to model a skirt like [this one](http://www.essentialschoolwear.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/l/black-pleated-designer-skirt-bm.jpg), so I have a Bezier Circle to describe the curve of the waist, an a mesh for each pleat. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUyKm.jpg), it looks fine, except the mesh is not being replicated around the curve completely. If I change the Constant Offset, I can only make the gap so small before one of the meshes disappears.

Is there a way I can fill that hole in the skirt by making the mesh go all the way around?